# Localstorage in reactjs when it get reloaded key is present values are missing

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const initialValues = { username:"", password: "" };
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState(initialValues);
  const [formErrors, setFormErrors] = useState({});
  const [isSubmit, setIsSubmit] = useState(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data")) ? true : false
  );

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormValues({ ...formValues, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setFormErrors(validate(formValues));
    setIsSubmit(true);
  };

  const validate = (values) => {
    const errors = {};
    if (!values.username) {
      errors.username = "Username is required!";
    }

    if (!values.password) {
      errors.password = "Password is required";
    } else if (values.password.length < 4) {
      errors.password = "Password must be more than 4 characters";
    } else if (values.password.length > 8) {
      errors.password = "Password cannot exceed more than 10 characters";
    }
    return errors;
  };
  const logout = () => {
    setIsSubmit(false);
    localStorage.clear();
  };



  return (
    <div className="container">
      {Object.keys(formErrors).length === 0 && isSubmit ? (
        <>
         {localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(formValues))}
          <div>
            hello {JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data")).username} ,Signed
            in successfully
          </div>
          <button onClick={logout}>LOG OUT</button>
        </>
      ) : (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div>
            <div>
              <label>Username</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="username"
                placeholder="Username"
                value={formValues.username}
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </div>
            <p>{formErrors.username}</p>
            <div>
              <label>Password</label>
              <input
                type="password"
                name="password"
                placeholder="Password"
                value={formValues.password}
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </div>
            <p>{formErrors.password}</p>
            <button>Submit</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[once data stored in storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcgSd.png)

[when it get reloaded keys are present but value missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIwV6.png)

when form is getting reloaded the data which is stored in the from of object in localStorage the values are getting missed while key are present.when form is getting reloaded the data which is stored in the from of object in local Storage the values are getting missed while key are present.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `handleSubmit` func instead of returning the data to the local storage, as you can see in the code below.

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setFormErrors(validate(formValues));
    setIsSubmit(true);
    localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(formValues));
};
```

Remove this line `{localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(formValues))}` in `return` method.